# Why does communication still works after deleting pipe file?

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

process1.cpp:

```
const char* myfifo = "./myfifo";
mkfifo(myfifo,0666);
fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
wait(0);
read(fd, &sum, 4);
```

process2.cpp:

```
fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
unlink(myfifo);
write(fd, &write_int, sizeof(write_int) );
```

At first, I created a pipe file named **myfifo** using **mkfifo()**,then gave the descriptor of **myfifo** to process1 and process2,then use **unlink()** to delete **myfifo**.
The whole program works, but it is weird that I can still read and write between two processes after deleting **myfifo**. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink): *If the name referred to a socket, fifo or device the name for it is removed but processes which have the object open may continue to use it.*

Answer (score 0):

When you `unlink()` a file, the file is actually removed from file system if and only if:

- all other links are deleted, and
- no other processes have open file descriptors referencing the same file